# How do I catch IntegrityError in Django when using UniqueConstraint across multiple fields?

Tags: django, duplicates, unique-constraint

I have a model with user as 1 field (Foreign Key) and one other field skill_group. I need to make sure the user does not add duplicate skill groups so I added a UniqueConstraint. This is working as the system errors out with IntegrityError at /skillgroup/create/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_skillgroup" - How do I catch this exception and notify user if duplicate; otherwise save it?

New to Django/Python/Postgres and I thought I could handle it by overriding the save() function, but there is no access to user which is part of the check and I have read this should not be handled here. Is there a try/save catch/message I should be employing? I have tried a few things with no luck. I have seen similar questions on here, but they have not helped. Any help is appreciated.

```
models.py
class SkillGroup(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill_group = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    sequence = models.IntegerField(default=999)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'skill_group'], name='unique_skillgroup'),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.skill_group

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('skillgroup-list')
```

```
views.py
class SkillGroupCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = SkillGroup
    fields = ['skill_group']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.sequence = SkillGroup.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('sequence').last().sequence + 1
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

```
skillgroup_form.html
{% extends "recruiter/baseskills.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content%}
  <div class="content-section">
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Skill Group</legend>
          {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add Skill Group</button>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
{% endblock content%}
```

I want to either catch the exception and save the record if not a duplicate or put message on screen saying "Skill Group already exists" and leave user on create page. Also, I could remove the UniqueConstraint and handle with code if that is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inadvertently bypassing Django's form validation here and then trying to save invalid input to the database, which is why Django is feeding back an ugly IntegrityError from the database instead of handling the error gracefully.

If you submit a duplicate User and SkillGroup in your form, your `CreateView` will helpfully return the error message back into your form template:

- "Skill group with this User and Skill group already exists."

But it can only do this if you include a `User` field in your form. I assume you have excluded User to keep the form template tidy, but that prevents Django's form validation from checking if the combination already exists.

To get around this, add `User` to your form field as a hidden input. I don't think that's possible using `CreateView`'s behind-the-scenes magic, so you'll need to create a `SkillGroupForm` to handle that.

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import SkillGroup

class SkillGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SkillGroup
        fields = ('user', 'skill_group')
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.HiddenInput,
        }

# views.py
from .forms import SkillGroupForm

class SkillGroupCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = SkillGroup
    form_class = SkillGroupForm

    def get_initial(self):
        return {'user': self.request.user}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.sequence = SkillGroup.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('sequence').last().sequence + 1
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The `get_initial` method passes the `request.user` as an initial value into the hidden form field, so no user input is needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I read so many solutions on many websites and nowhere did I see anything about adding the user to the form.

Comment: Excelent answer, thank you! Seems in case of UpdateView the (view.)get_initial() method is not required and adding of HiddenInput into (form.)Meta is enough.

Comment: This fixes it, but if I'm not mistaken, it makes it possible for the client to modify the hidden input and with it change the user, which should not be possible. To prevent it you would need to override whatever comes from that input in form_valid by adding form.instance.user = self.request.user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate **skill_group** field inside your form class. Define **clean_skill_group** method [like in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).There you can get queryset of all SkillGroup objects related to your User (like [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)) and then compare skills. But you need to push somehow your User object or user_id (to get then User object) to the form before **form.is_valid()** will be called (or call one more time **form.is_valid()** after). Then show form errors in your html template.

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ....some fields, Meta....
    def clean_skill_group(self):
        your_user_object = ....
        previously_created_skills = your_user_object.skill_group_set.all()
        skill_input = self.cleaned_data["skill_group"]
        if skill_input in previously_created_skills:
            raise forms.ValidationError(("This skill group is already exist"), code="invalid") # I suppose you are using model form
```

Comment: Thank you. First solution worked, but this was the way to solve it without using UniqueConstraint. Appreciate the input!